# How to reset an incremental achievement in Googles Android API?

Tags: unity, android, google-play-services

For example the achievement is "Pass 5 levels in a row without failing"

It's incremental and has five steps.

**If a user hits an obstacle, this achievements score should obviously be resetted to 0.**

How to to this? I found no such method or anything in the internet.

Answer (score 2):

You don’t. This would need to be simply a single-step achievement.

Comment: So it's not even possible?

Comment: @Squareoot it's possible, but tracking the increments of "3/5 levels passed without failing" happens in your game code, not in Google's back-end. Since that variable lives in your code (or on your server if you need to persist it between game sessions, depending on how strictly you define "in a row"), you can reset it to zero anytime you want. Once the variable hits 5, only then do you report to Google "This single-step achievement is complete!"

Comment: @DMGregory thanks I understand.